# Swift Async/Await with Combine Publisher unit testing

Tags: swift, async-await, combine

I have a codebase where we have a mixture of Async/Await and combine, while running it seems to work fine, however testing is another matter entirely. Publishers are easy enough to get deterministic output on as you can wait for the expectation or even inject a different thread for them to run making them execute immediately. Async/Await however does not give you this control. I have tried running `try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)` with some limited success but it is a tad flakey and does not always work.

Here is the code im currently trying to pass on tests

```
lazy var searchTests: AnyPublisher<Result<LabTestResultPage, Error>, Never> = searchSub
      .compactMap { $0 }
      .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
      .map { [unowned self] in search(searchParams: $0) }
      .switchToLatest()
      .share()
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

and the Async/Await method that is being called is here

```
private func search(searchParams: SearchTestsParams) -> AnyPublisher<Result<LabTestResultPage, Error>, Never> {
        Deferred { [searchTestsUseCase] in
          Future { promise in
            Task {
              do {
                promise(.success(.success(try await searchTestsUseCase.execute(with: searchParams))))
              } catch {
                promise(.success(.failure(error)))
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
```

Has anyone got these to work nicely together when testing?

Comment: Could you explain yours problem? You can use expectations in async tasks and inject threads using actors.

Comment: I don’t think they belong together. https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-async-algorithms/

Comment: @Cy-4AH the issue is that when im testing and the call im testing in this case calls a publisher which then invokes something on a `Task` as you see above, sometimes the test fails because the Task has not completed yet unless in my test i put `try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)` and even then it's not always guarenteed. But you mentioned actors, is there a way to Inject an actor that runs synchronously just for testing purposes?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations. Its not a problem to call `fullFill` in the async task. Why you add `Task.sleep` if you need wait task completion, not to delay it?

Comment: @Cy-4AH the fulfill works for the code in the `Combine` part, its the code thats wraped in a `Task` that is the issue. To elaborate, push a value into the publisher, that we can await and fulfill fine, once that code then get's to the function that is an API call that call is wrapped in a `Task` as you can see above. that code is not being triggered unless i use `Task.sleep`, but while writing this I think i got what you mean, another expectation awaiting the value for the code wrapped in the Task you mean?

Comment: @Genhain yes all async calls: completion blocks, Combine, async Tasks should have expectations: you don't want exit from test function until all async work is done. You can create several expectations or use `expectedFulfillmentCount` property. As you wish.

Comment: This should work with `XCTestExpectation`, assuming you inject a mocked `searchTestsUseCase` which immediately returns some dummy from the `execute(with: searchParams)` call.